# How to write SQL query to count values that meets multiple column conditions with multiple column exclusions?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL as the database.

I have a joined table with two fields ItemGroupID and CheckNumber that apply to this query.

A CheckNumber can contain multiple ItemGroupIDs, and ItemGroupIDs can contain multiple CheckNumbers

I'm attempting to count the number of checks that meet multiple conditions (has item group 281 and item group 274, but does not have item group 280 or 34 in any record. Here's a snippet of the joined table.

```
ItemGroupID | CheckNumber
-----------   -----------
    281           101
    274           101
    103           101
    281           101
    280           102
    281           102
    274           102
    281           103
```

For the above table, the query should only return a count of 1 for CheckNumber 101 since it has both id 281 and 274, and it doesn't contain 280 or 34.The other check numbers should not return a count. CheckNumber 102 has an excluded GroupID on the check. CheckNumber 103 doesn't contain 281 AND 274.

Below is the query I've written. The issue with the query is that it doesn't exclude the checks with the ItemGroupID 280 or 34. I believe it's an issue with the Count function in GROUP BY. But I'm unsure how to rewrite it to fix this issue.

```
SELECT COUNT(id.CheckNumber) AS Total
FROM ItemGroupMember igm
    INNER JOIN ItemDetail id ON igm.ItemID = id.ItemID
WHERE igm.ItemGroupID IN (281,274)
    AND NOT igm.ItemGroupID IN (280,34)
    AND id.DOB BETWEEN 3/14/2017 AND 3/14/2017
    AND id.LocationID = 22
GROUP BY id.CheckNumber HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT igm.ItemGroupID) = 2
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Missing one piece of key information here - What is it that you are having trouble with. You explain clearly what you want to achieve, and showed what you have tried, but haven't explained why your attempt has yet to work. Quickly update your question with that info

Comment: @Takarii Thanks for the suggestion, just edited with the issue I'm getting with my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

Data:

```
create table exp (
  ItemGroupID int,
  CheckNumber int
  );

  Insert into exp values (281, 101) ;
  Insert into exp values (274, 101) ;
  Insert into exp values (103, 101) ;
  Insert into exp values (281, 101) ;
  Insert into exp values (280, 102) ;
  Insert into exp values (281, 102) ;
  Insert into exp values (274, 102) ;
  Insert into exp values (281, 103) ;
```

Query:

```
Select checknumber, count(*)
From exp
Where
exists (Select e1.ItemGroupID From exp e1 Where e1.checknumber = exp.checknumber and e1.ItemGroupID in (281))
and exists (Select e1.ItemGroupID From exp e1 Where e1.checknumber = exp.checknumber and e1.ItemGroupID in (274))
and not exists (Select e1.ItemGroupID From exp e1 Where e1.checknumber = exp.checknumber and e1.ItemGroupID in (280, 34))
Group by checknumber
```

Real data:

```
Select checknumber, count(*)
From (Select * From ItemGroupMember igm INNER JOIN ItemDetail id ON igm.ItemID = id.ItemID WHERE id.DOB BETWEEN 3/14/2017 AND 3/14/2017 AND id.LocationID = 22) exp
Where
    exists (Select e1.ItemGroupID From (Select * From ItemGroupMember igm INNER JOIN ItemDetail id ON igm.ItemID = id.ItemID WHERE id.DOB BETWEEN 3/14/2017 AND 3/14/2017 AND id.LocationID = 22) e1 Where e1.checknumber = exp.checknumber and e1.ItemGroupID in (281))
    and exists (Select e1.ItemGroupID From (Select * From ItemGroupMember igm INNER JOIN ItemDetail id ON igm.ItemID = id.ItemID WHERE id.DOB BETWEEN 3/14/2017 AND 3/14/2017 AND id.LocationID = 22) e1 Where e1.checknumber = exp.checknumber and e1.ItemGroupID in (274))
    and not exists (Select e1.ItemGroupID From (Select * From ItemGroupMember igm INNER JOIN ItemDetail id ON igm.ItemID = id.ItemID WHERE id.DOB BETWEEN 3/14/2017 AND 3/14/2017 AND id.LocationID = 22) e1 Where e1.checknumber = exp.checknumber and e1.ItemGroupID in (280, 34))
Group by checknumber
```

Comment: Thank you Demo. Looks like this is a solve. Unfortunately, I don't have access to create tables in my current environment, unless I export the table to excel then import into a locally hosted database.

Comment: These are just dummy data, instead of exp you'll fill in your querry as an subquery. I take it that "HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT igm.ItemGroupID) = 2" is not part of it. I'll try to add this to the answer

Comment: @Robert Abdallah I edited the answer. Does that work? I wasn't completely sure what you want to count so I just counted the number of occurrences of ItemGroupIDs within each selected CheckNumber

Comment: Thanks for the help and apologize for the back and forth. I'm a newbie to SQL and subquery syntax. The query above is throwing errors. It's saying the column ItemID was specified multiple times for exp, e1, e1, e1. My end solution should give me the number of distinct check numbers that have item group 281 AND 274, but do not include 280 or 34. If a checknumber record has 280 or 34 itemGroup, then that check number should be removed, not only for that specific record, but on all records in the table. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: @Robert Abdallah Every query (regardless of whether it is the uppermost one or a subquery) returns results in form of a table. When you think about it this way, it's easy to nest the queries since you can simply regard them as tables. "(Select * From mytable)" is pretty much equivalent to "mytable". The problem is probably in the "*" in the subqueries since there are two "ItemID"s. Try specifying the columns (igm.checknumber; igm.ItemGroupID). Sorry I'm unable to be precise without having the data available :( To count distinct checknumber, omit group by and just count(distinct checknumber).

Comment: Perfect, you were right, just needed to specify the table for each field name. One question, what's happening in the exists condition when we put e1.checknumber = exp.checknumber?

Comment: @Robert Abdallah the EXISTS condition evaluates true when the subquery returns anything at all, otherwise it's false. By e1.checknumber = exp.checknumber you're making a connection between the upper query and the subquery. For each row of exp the EXISTS conditions are evaluated and current exp.checknumber value is put in its condition. Without this, the subquery wouldn't be constrained and would just return all the records and thus all the exists would return true (unless the subquery tables are empty). Try: `Select 'hello' greeting From dual Where exists (Select 'hmm' From dual Where 1 = 1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(id.CheckNumber) AS Total
FROM ItemDetail id
JOIN ItemGroupMember igm ON igm.ItemID = id.ItemID AND igm.ItemGroupID IN (281,274)
LEFT JOIN ItemGroupMember igm2 ON igm2.ItemID = id.ItemID AND igm2.ItemGroupID IN (280,34)
WHERE 
    id.DOB BETWEEN 3/14/2017 AND 3/14/2017
    AND id.LocationID = 22
    AND igm2.ItemID is null -- Make sure that you exclude any where the groupID is 280 or 34
group by id.CheckNumber having Total = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This looks promising, but the multiple inner joins are returning no records. Any fix for this? Also, if I understand it correctly, the 'is null' operator selects records that do not have the 280,34 item group, correct? But since CheckNumber 102 in the example has a record for 281, and another record for 280, the 280 would be removed, but the 281 would still be there. Therefore, check number 102 would count as 1?